# change qTip tool tip in elements in multiple TDs on toggle

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue using the qTip plugin with jQuery. I've created a js fiddle to see what it's doing. I'm not sure exactly how to fix this (the link is after the description of the issue)

So I have what's going to be a check list. You'll see three `<tr>` w/ a tooltip on each. If the task is not done the tool tip says "task not complete". If the task is done the tooltip says "task complete."

When you click on "toggle" it's supposed to change the `<span>` in the `<tr>` to fade in/out and toggle a class and change the tooltip from "complete" to "not complete" and vice versa.

Everything else seems to work properly. It changes the class, it fades in/out, and it even changes the title attribute.

The problem is that the qTip plugin only changes the tooltip in the cell directly to the right of the toggle. It doesn't change the tooltip in the following two cells.

Everything seems to be in order for it to work properly. Any ideas what's going on? This is driving me crazy!!

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNCCn/4/)

Comment: Hey man try this: seems to be working (i.e. adject column 3 and 4 also have correct tooltip) I am using safari & osx lion: http://jsfiddle.net/ZQ5ZW/ ; please let me know if I am missing a point, cheers!

Comment: @Tats_innit this seems to be the same code as my example. It doesn't look like anything has changed. Can you verify this is the correct link?

Comment: Hiya, Indeed I forked your solution, if you will read my comment I mentioned that it seems to be behaving correct: "(i.e. adject column 3 and 4 also have correct tooltip)" but I reckon I definitely misunderstood, any who let me know if I did missed a point, :) cheers and a have a good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

**1)** Instead of

```
.attr('title', 'This task is not yet complete.');
```

use

```
.qtip('option', {'content.text': 'This task is not yet complete.'});
```

qTip actually copies the `title` attribute (it does not bind to it) when initialized, so in order to change qTip you need to alter it via [qTip methods](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/api/#methods).

**2)** Set qTip's content to a jQuery object. For example add `data-qtip` attribute to your titled elements which will be (for example) an id of qtip content's container (add additional div for each qtip):

```
$('[data-qtip]').each(function() {
    var q = $(this).attr('data-qtip');
    var content = $('#'+q);

    $(this).qtip({
        content: content, // here we reference the jQuery object
        position: {
            my: 'bottom center',
            at: 'top center'
        },
        style: { classes: 'ui-tooltip-dark ui-tooltip-rounded' }
    }
});
```

Now changing the content of divs will change the qtip (because this is actually a binding).

Personally I think that the second solution is better. It gives you nice control over qTip and it worked really well for me when I worked on dynamic tooltips (for example tooltip with an interactive chart).

Comment: Hey Freakish, thanks for your help. So question about option 2. Is the "data-qtip" going to be the new "tooltip" - for instance: `data-qtip="tooltip hover goes here"`?  When I do the toggle function, exactly how do I say what the new text will be? `.attr("data-qtip","new text after toggle");`? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JeremyMiller This div with attribute `data-qtip` will be you qtip. You can use normal jQuery to change its content (for example) like this: `$('[data-tip]').html('My <span>new</span> content.');`. Changing the content of the div will automatically change the content of tooltip.